# Mount Network Shares for Plex - Ubuntu 16.04LTS

Tags: mount, fstab, automount

I am trying to learn about the ways of Linux, coming from a Windows and Mac background. I can't seem to get a simple Network Share to stay persistent for a Linux Plex Server.

I have the following in my `/etc/fstab`:

```
//nas.local/video/Movies /home/magwezie/Plex/Movies cifs user:xxxx pass:xxxx
```

(note `xxxx` is actually my username and password).

It worked initially, but after a few mishaps it will not remap. I can connect using the Files application.

Comment: OK so I have been reviewing the answers, however problem still exists. I have made some changes based on the readings from below. FSTAB now reads : 
//nas.local/video/Movies /home/magwezie/Plex/Movies cifs rw username:xxx password:xxx 0 0

Answer (score 0):

The way you entered username and password looks incorrect to me.
Your `fstab` line to mount a CIFS volume should read:

```
//nas.local/video/Movies /home/magwezie/Plex/Movies cifs rw,username=xxx,password=xxx 0 0
```

The mount options should be separated by `,` (not space), their names and values should be separated by `=` (not `:`). You may also include the last two parameters – `dump` and `pass` but they’re optional. They should be both `0` (default value) for a network drive.

See [`man fstab`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/fstab.5.html) for details (emphasis mine):

> **The fourth field (fs_mntops).**
>
> This field describes the mount options associated with the filesystem.
>
> It is formatted as a **comma-separated list** of options. It contains at least the
>   type of mount (`ro` or `rw`), plus any additional options appropriate to the filesystem
>   type  (including performance-tuning options). For details, see [mount(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) or [swapon(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/swapon.8.html).

Look also at [`man mount.cifs`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs) to see how individual options should be formatted, e.g.:

> ```
> username=arg
> ```
>
> specifies the username to connect as. If this is not given, then the environment variable USER is used.

### Host identification – another possible problem

Moreover, I recommend using IP address instead of a hostname like `nas.local`. The hostname in the local network might be discovered later and not be available during boot.